# Custom Resource Provider

Tags: localization

I am using custom resource provider in Asp.Net to get the data from the external resource files, After changing the browser language it does not select the proper translation. i.e. It always returns English version. On the other side, if i use Asp.Net tag

It returns the correct translation. I configured it in web.config

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i figured out by myself. In my custom resouce provider, i was passing the cultureinfo by myself. I change it to null and it started working. Its wiered but worked for me.